# Error in side by side box plotting

Tags: r

I am trying to write code for box plotting in R but I am getting an error saying:

> Error in x[flooring(d)] + x[ceiling(d)], non numeric argument to binary operator.

my data set is Cars_csv and I have to bring all cars having 4 and 6 cylinders and plot them against highway fuel economy using side by side box plotting.
I dont know how to solve it!
can someone please help me!
the code is like,

```
install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplo2)
cars_filtered <- Cars_csv %>% filter(Cylinders == 4 | Cylinders == 6)
Cars_csv %>% boxplot(cars_filtered ~ Cars_csv$Economy_highway)
```

Comment: Why load `ggplot2`? The graphic function you are using is a base R function.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're looking for something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == 4 | cyl == 6) %>%
    ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = "free_x")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4,6))
```

[image]